# How to format decimal in django template, in a input tag

Tags: django, templates, format

I know I can use floatformat, but works only if I pass a number as parameter.. if I try to use {{ myform.myfield }} doesn't work.

There's any plugin to format a decimal field using {{ myform.myfield }} ? I know, I can write all inputs tag, but take some time, and I'm looking for something easer to use..

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "I know I can use floatformat, but works only if I pass a number as parameter"?  `{{ myform.myfield|floatformat }}` should absolutely work.

Comment: The problem is, in my country the number is 150,00; and sometimes I get one error using floatformat. But Looking in the net, I found the solution: User Localize in all Decimal fields into the Form, after that use l10n in a template. If you want to use the number without format, use myfield.value|unlocalize. That's works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, in my country the number is 150,00; and sometimes I get one error using floatformat. But Looking in the net, I found the solution: User Localize in all Decimal fields into the Form:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    new_class = super(MyForm, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    for field in new_class.base_fields.values():
        if isinstance(field, DecimalField):
            field.localize = True
            field.widget.is_localized = True
    return new_class
```

After that use l10n in a template. If you want to use the number without format, use myfield.value|unlocalize, like this:

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load l10n %}

(....)
{{ myfield.pk|unlocalize }}
```

That's works for me.